# Can't pull objects updated attributes from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After updating object attributes in my db, I can't seem to retrieve the values back in a subsequent method call. At the point I attempt to retrieve the data, I've confirmed the attributes have updated in my db.

```
def task
  update_objects(data)
  retrieve_data
end

def update_objects(data)
   data.each do |item|
     keyword = self.keywords.find_by_description(item.keyword)
     keyword.update_attributes(:total_value => item.totalValue.to_f, :avg_revenue_per_transaction => item.revenuePerTransaction.to_f)
    end
end

def retrieve_data
   keywords = self.keywords # The updated attributes in keywords are nil

   # Do stuff with keywords
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `keywords` collection has probably already loaded before you call `retrieve_data`.  However, calling `find_by_description` doesn't make use of the loaded collection (since it's using the query API) and fetches a new object from the database directly which you are updating.  The original loaded collection doesn't know about this.  There are several ways to fix this:

You can call `reload` to refresh the collection from the database:

```
def retrieve_data
  keywords = self.keywords(true)
end
```

Or don't use the query API, but rather use the collection itself:

```
 keyword = self.keywords.detect{|k| k.description == item.keyword}
```

Or simply avoid loading the collection in advance.